# My java source files cannot be commited

Tags: java, eclipse, github, egit

i am creating a small Java project and wish to put in on GitHub using eclipse.

Everything is working fine until i go to Team -> Commit, my source files aren't there.

I don't know what to do so i could commit my .java files, any ideas?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, there were about 4 files in the Files section, but none of them were the java files.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you skipped the "add to the index" part: you need to add files, before committing.

See [Track Changes](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Track_Changes).

> Click `Team > Add to Index` on the project node. (This menu item is named `Add` on older versions of Egit.)

If you don't add anything, the commit will be empty.

See also "[Git Basics - Recording Changes to the Repository](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository)".

Comment: I did Team > Add To Index but that didn't work, there are no files in the Files section.

Comment: @nestorishimo10 try again from scratch, importing your existing .project in a new git repo: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Wizard_for_project_import

Comment: I started over, did Team > Add To Index and then did commit, still no luck.

Comment: @nestorishimo10 is it possible that those sources are already added and commited in the git repo?

Comment: No, i checked, and it wasent in the repository.